# Tableau finding and marking duplicate rows

Tags: tableau-api

I have used the level of detail expression outlined in another post in which I'm trying to mark duplicate records as matched.  I'm using a level of detail calculation that seems to work sometimes but not al the time.  As you can see in my results sometimes it shows matched even though there is only on Server and Application name combination. Here is the calculations formula that I'm using as well as a view of my results.  Any insight would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

This is the matched column calculation...

```
'''if {fixed str([Servers with Token Deployed])+str([App Name]): count([Number of Records])}>1 then 'Yes' else 'No' End'''
```

Comment: What dimensions have you added to your Rows shelf? Is there a reason why you're concatenating the dimensions instead of actually looking for count greater than one across the natural dimensions themselves (something like `{FIXED [Servers with Token Deployed], [App Name] : COUNT(1) > 1 }` )?

Comment: I tried using the natural dimensions as you suggested, but got the same results.  my row dimensions are:  Serial, Domain, Servers with Token Deployed, App Name,  Source, Matched.  (Serial is a calculated field - Index().   I was going to attach my .twbx file but can't figure out how to.

Comment: If you have duplicate rows in your data, it is usually a lot  more reliable to eliminate the duplicates in a pre-processing step, perhaps using Tableau Prep, than to tolerate/ignore duplicate data during the analysis and visualization stages. There are lots of ways for it to go wrong if you leave the duplicates in place

Comment: My issue was in my data source I was including more data than I intended because of a join. @AlexBlakemore That's a good point but in this case I needed to see duplicates when there were duplicates.